# Can the GetHashCode() method of a string return zero?

Tags: .net, hashcode

When obtaining the hash code of a string using the `GetHashCode()` method is there any chance that it can return zero or does the algorithm used guarantee otherwise?

The reason I'm asking is that I have a use case where I need to invent a hash for a null string and I was thinking of using zero rather than hashing some constant string.  If I do this how likely am I to get a collision (barring the obvious fact that collisions are always possible)

Comment: Would anything actually change in your code if the answer was “Yes, `string.GetHashCode()` can sometimes return 0”?

Comment: No, given that collisions can always happen any number would do, choosing zero over some other arbitrary constant just seems more sensible in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to definitively answer that.  The behavior of [String.GetHashCode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode.aspx) is documented as being undefined and subject to change between framework versions and to be different between 32bit and 64 bit systems.

If you chose some other value you may be just as likely to have a collision.  Zero would be a pretty reasonable default.

The [Nullable.GetHashCode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axk9ks7d.aspx) returns 0 if it stores a null value so return a hash code for zero has some precedent.

Comment: There exist strings which hash to zero.  For all practical purposes, the original question can definitely be answered "yes".  The only way in which the answer could be anything other than an unqualified "yes" would be if the question was something like "will it always be possible to find a string which hashes to zero".  Incidentally, if I were designing a framework, I would specify that a good `GetHashCode()` implementation should never return zero "slowly"; if a hash function that takes significant time to execute yields zero, `GetHashCode` should return something else.

Comment: If such a rule existed, classes that are considering caching hash codes based on need could safely use zero to indicate "hash not cached", since even if a few objects ended up having GetHashCode called on them all the time, it wouldn't have much effect.  Without such a rule, there's a danger that a program that needs to perform lots of comparisons among objects with slow-to-compute hash codes might run quickly most of the time until an object gets created which hashes to zero, whereupon performance could degrade by an order of magnitude or more.

Answer (score 2):

`GetHashCode()` only requires the hashcode to be consistent. It does not need to be unique. So zero is a valid but very naive hash value :)

Obviously, this will cause many collisions in a hashtable.

As for a string hashcode, I guess in some conditions that will be possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is risky, a null string can get coerced to an empty string.  For example:

```
        string nullstr = null;
        string notnull = nullstr + nullstr;
```

A bit outlandish perhaps, but you'll have a helluvatime debugging the problem when it happens.  The simple solution is to use string.Empty.GetHashCode(), there's no requirement whatsoever that the hash code is unique.